# Using the predict() function with glm

Tags: r, regression, glm

Let's say that I have the following data set and am running a regression model using glm in R. I have the coefficients, but I want to predict "next months" value (visits). How would I go about that in this example.

```
d <- data.frame(month = c("jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "june"),
                visit =  c( 1,  2,  4,  8, 16, 32),
                click =  c(64, 62, 36,  5,  6,  3),
                conv =  c(1, 3, 6, 2, 3, 8))
d
dFit <- glm(visit ~ click + conv, data=d)
```

For July, how can I use the `predict()` function in R to predict the number of visits (response variable)?

EDIT:

What I'm trying to eventually get is an out put where I have

```
Mon   Pred_clicks
jan   20
feb   25
mar   21
apr   31
may   15
june  21 
july  50
```

EDIT 2:

This isn't the output I'd like

```
> predict(dFit)
        1         2         3         4         5         6 
-3.452974  1.223969 13.533457 12.235771 14.113888 25.345890
```

Comment: even without worrying about whether you have data for July, I'm having a hard time seeing where your expected predicted values for, say, January are coming from?

Answer (score 4):

Since you trained the model with a `data.frame` which contained the columns `month`, `click` and `conv`, you will have to provide such a `data.frame` to predict the values as well:

```R
 predict(dFit, data.frame(month="july", conv=mean(d$conv), click=mean(d$click)))
```

The `mean(d$conv)` and `mean(d$click)` are the *predicted* values for the respective quantities for the month of July. If you have the actual values of `conv` and `click` for the month of July, substitute them in the statement to get your prediction.

However, that is probably not what you are looking for and GLMs regression may not be the best model to for this sort of time series data. I think you would want to use [VAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_autoregression) as your predictive model.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a data frame containing July's data named `newdata`, you would just do:

```
predict(dFit,newdata)
```

If you don't have data for July then it is not possible.